# Changing variables from one nib to another

Tags: iphone, function, xib

Let's say I have:

```
FirstViewController.h
FirstViewController.m
FirstViewController.xib

SecondViewController.h
SecondViewController.m
SecondViewController.xib
```

In the FirstViewController.h there is:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    int number;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) int number;
@end
```

And in FirstViewController.m there is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    int number = 4;
}
```

Is there a way that I could write a function for SecondViewController that could change the value for int number from 4 to let's say 9?

I don't know how to change variables from another XIB or .m file...

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably don't mean to `retain` an `int.

Second, you do not need to declare `int number = 4;` but just `number = 4;`.

Third, if the `SecondViewController` can access an instance of the `FirstViewController *firstViewController`, then it can change the value by

`[firstViewController setNumber:9];`

Depending on your hierarchy, you may be able to access `firstViewController` through the `navController` stack, for example.

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake with retain and int number = 4.

Comment: I have a main view which shows an int value, and I want to change it from another view with a function call, but I can't access the number variable

Comment: The actual code from FirstViewController is:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"236", @"46",
                   @"147", @"8", @"56", @"69", @"114", @"2",
                   @"96", @"518", @"2", @"54", @"236", nil];
    self.listData = array;
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

And I want to add an object to that array from another view with a button click, how can I do that?
How can I access listData from SecondViewController?

Comment: @Wikiboo: I'm not going to attempt to read unformatted code, especially in a comment. If you do not explain your view hierarchy and, in particular, how the `SecondViewController` accesses the `FirstViewController`, then I cannot possibly give you an answer.